# How Configure pgAgent in Ubuntu22.04?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, ubuntu-22.04, pgagent

I have installed postgresql, pgAdmin, and pgAgent. However, I can't get pgAgent to work with pgAdmin. It's been 3 days already, and I have no clue what I need to do.

**What commands did I use for the installation?**

```
sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib
sudo apt install pgadmin4
sudo apt-get -y install pgagent
```

And you can see the extension is installed but not the options to create the job with pgAgent

[1]

**I tried to follow the instructions on the official website, but their command is not working.**

[2]

And this is the result

[3]

host=localhost...host=127.0.0.1 ....the same result....

Thanks for you attention
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpq4A.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfpjB.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eHwp.png

Comment: "but their command is not working"  Share Why you think it is "not working", and which documentation you actually used.

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) does not say you should use _**answer**_ to clarify your question. Someone invented [edit] for that purpose... 

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the previous post... I didn't realize that Stack Overflow messed up the formatting

**Sources used for the installation of pgAdmin.**

https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/pgagent_install.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ne8Jg_lQldQ

What I have understood is that PostgreSQL is a service for managing databases. PgAdmin is a program that allows you to manage the database more easily.

And pgAgent is a plugin that you install to create routines easily. Well, pgAgent runs in the background as a system service.

What I'm looking for is to have that menu that facilitates creating routine tasks.
[image]

**I believe this is what is failing.**

I think after install pgagent with *"sudo apt install pgagent"* and install de plugin in the database with *"CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plpgsql"*;

You need to create that service or somehow ensure that pgAgent is running as a system service. If that's the case, I have no idea how to do that. I understand that after installing pgAgent with 'sudo apt install pgagent,' the service is automatically created, but you need to specify which database it should connect to.

For that, I believe the command '/path/to/pgagent hostaddr=127.0.0.1 dbname=postgres user=postgres' is used, as mentioned on the official website, so that pgAdmin can use it. However, I'm encountering this error.

[image]

I want to understand that if you manage to establish that connection, pgAdmin will have that menu where you can easily create routines.